# appending something to a bookmarklet-generated url

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm using a bookmarklet to post URLs to my [known](https://withknown.com) installation.

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://xyz/known/share?share_url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&share_title\='+encodeURIComponent(document.title));})();
```

This returns the URL:

> http://xyz/known/share?share_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stichpunkt.de%2Fbookmarklets%2F&share_title=Bookmarklets

I want to have

```
&share_type=bookmark
```

appended to the url, yet since I don't understand JavaScript, fail to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://xyz/known/share?share_url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&share_title\='+encodeURIComponent(document.title) + '&share_type=bookmark');})();
```